# How to use variables from another class in one class?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5

There is a class with a tab, inside of which there are several widgets that have an **Add** button, and I want to make sure that when this button is clicked, this widget is added to the **TEST** window, but I don’t know how to implement it correctly.

Here is the main window code:

```
import sys
#from STYLE import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import time
import random

from korzina import Korzina





class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("TEST")

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)

        vbox.addWidget(EgorWindow(), 1)

        #Создаем QTabWidget для товаров
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        font = QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12)
        self.tab.setFont(font)




        # Создаем вкладку
        self.sales = Sales(self)
        self.tab.addTab(self.sales, " 123  ")
        #self.tab.setStyleSheet(qssTab)
        vbox.addWidget(self.tab, 1) 





class EgorWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(EgorWindow, self).__init__(parent)
      

        self.title = QWidget(self)
        self.title.setFixedSize(2000,540)
        
      

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        

        label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2000, 540))
           

          
            
        label.setFixedSize(1920, 540)
       
     
        
      
       


        def openKor(self):
            kor = Korzina()
            kor.exec_()

        #Кнопка корзины
        self.button_kor = QtWidgets.QPushButton('TEST')
        #self.button_kor.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet_kor)
        self.button_kor.setGeometry(1835, 140, 60, 60)
        self.button_kor.clicked.connect(openKor)
        self.button_kor.setParent(self.title)


        

        



        
        

             







class Sales(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #FFFFFF')

        layoutV = QVBoxLayout(self)

        layoutV.addWidget(self.scroll)

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setStyleSheet('background-color: #e6e6fa')


        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)
       

        self.gbox = QGridLayout(self.widget)
        self.gbox.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.gbox.setSpacing(10)
        #первый виджет
        self.widget1 = QLabel()
        self.widget1.setFixedSize(450, 300)
        self.widget1.setStyleSheet('background-color: white')
       

        self.childwidget1 = QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.childwidget1.setGeometry(0, 275, 450, 25)
        self.childwidget1.setStyleSheet("background-color:  #c5d0e6; color: black")
        self.childwidget1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 13))
        self.childwidget1.setText("2000")
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self.childwidget1)
        #self.btn1.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet_like)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(410, 0, 35, 25)
        
        self.btn3 = QPushButton(self.childwidget1)
        #self.btn2.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet_buy)
        self.btn3.setText('Add')
        self.btn3.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Century Gothic', 10))
        self.btn3.setGeometry(350, 0, 50, 25)


        
        #Попытка вставить виджет в другой класс
        def add(self, parent = None):
            

            gbox1.addWidget(self.widget1, 0,0)
           



        self.btn3.clicked.connect(add)

        #второй
        self.widget2 = QWidget()
        self.widget2.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget2.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")

        self.childwidget2 = QLabel(self.widget2)
        self.childwidget2.setGeometry(0, 275, 450, 25)
        self.childwidget2.setStyleSheet("background-color:  #c5d0e6; color: black")
        self.childwidget2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12))
        self.childwidget2.setText("2000")
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self.childwidget2)
        #self.btn1.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet_like)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(410, 0, 35, 25)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton(self.childwidget2)
        #self.btn2.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet_buy)
        self.btn2.setText('Add')
        self.btn2.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Century Gothic', 10))
        self.btn2.setGeometry(350, 0, 50, 25)

        #третий
        self.widget3 = QWidget()
        self.widget3.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget3.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")

        self.childwidget3 = QLabel(self.widget3)
        self.childwidget3.setGeometry(0, 275, 450, 25)
        self.childwidget3.setStyleSheet("background-color:  #c5d0e6; color: black")
        self.childwidget3.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12))
        self.childwidget3.setText("2000")
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self.childwidget3)
        #self.btn1.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet_like)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(410, 0, 35, 25)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton(self.childwidget3)
        #self.btn2.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet_buy)
        self.btn2.setText('Add')
        self.btn2.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Century Gothic', 10))
        self.btn2.setGeometry(350, 0, 50, 25)
        #четвертый
        self.widget4 = QWidget()
        self.widget4.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget4.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")

        self.childwidget4 = QLabel(self.widget4)
        self.childwidget4.setGeometry(0, 275, 450, 25)
        self.childwidget4.setStyleSheet("background-color:  #c5d0e6; color: black")
        self.childwidget4.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12))
        self.childwidget4.setText("2000")
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self.childwidget4)
        #self.btn1.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet_like)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(410, 0, 35, 25)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton(self.childwidget4)
        #self.btn2.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet_buy)
        self.btn2.setText('Add')
        self.btn2.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Century Gothic', 10))
        self.btn2.setGeometry(350, 0, 50, 25)
        #пятый
        self.widget5 = QWidget()
        self.widget5.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget5.setStyleSheet("background-color: grey")

        self.childwidget5 = QLabel(self.widget5)
        self.childwidget5.setGeometry(0, 275, 450, 25)
        self.childwidget5.setStyleSheet("background-color:  #c5d0e6; color: black")
        self.childwidget5.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12))
        self.childwidget5.setText("2000")
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self.childwidget5)
       
        self.btn1.setGeometry(410, 0, 35, 25)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton(self.childwidget5)
      
        self.btn2.setText('Add')
        self.btn2.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Century Gothic', 10))
        self.btn2.setGeometry(350, 0, 50, 25)
        #шестой
        self.widget6 = QWidget()
        self.widget6.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget6.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink")

        self.childwidget6 = QLabel(self.widget6)
        self.childwidget6.setGeometry(0, 275, 450, 25)
        self.childwidget6.setStyleSheet("background-color:  #c5d0e6; color: black")
        self.childwidget6.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12))
        self.childwidget6.setText("2000")
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self.childwidget6)
     
        self.btn1.setGeometry(410, 0, 35, 25)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton(self.childwidget6)
        
        self.btn2.setText('Add')
        self.btn2.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Century Gothic', 10))
        self.btn2.setGeometry(350, 0, 50, 25)
        #седьмой
        self.widget7 = QWidget()
        self.widget7.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget7.setStyleSheet("background-color: purpule")

        self.childwidget7 = QLabel(self.widget7)
        self.childwidget7.setGeometry(0, 275, 450, 25)
        self.childwidget7.setStyleSheet("background-color:  #c5d0e6; color: black")
        self.childwidget7.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12))
        self.childwidget7.setText("2000")
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self.childwidget7)
        #self.btn1.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet_like)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(410, 0, 35, 25)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton(self.childwidget7)
        #self.btn2.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet_buy)
        self.btn2.setText('Add')
        self.btn2.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Century Gothic', 10))
        self.btn2.setGeometry(350, 0, 50, 25)
        #восьмой
        self.widget8 = QWidget()
        self.widget8.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget8.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow")

        self.childwidget8 = QLabel(self.widget8)
        self.childwidget8.setGeometry(0, 275, 450, 25)
        self.childwidget8.setStyleSheet("background-color:  #c5d0e6; color: black")
        self.childwidget8.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12))
        self.childwidget8.setText("2000")
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self.childwidget8)
        #self.btn1.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet_like)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(410, 0, 35, 25)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton(self.childwidget8)
        #self.btn2.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet_buy)
        self.btn2.setText('Add')
        self.btn2.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Century Gothic', 10))
        self.btn2.setGeometry(350, 0, 50, 25)

        

        #Добавляем виджеты в layout
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget1, 0, 0)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget2, 0, 1)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget3, 0, 2)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget4, 0, 3)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget5, 1, 0)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget6, 1, 1)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget7, 1, 2)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget8, 1, 3)
















if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(1920, 1040)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Second window code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
#from main2 import LoginForm
#from main_window1 import TShort




class Korzina(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Korzina, self).__init__(parent)

        # Create Login Window
        self.setWindowTitle("Корзина")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("Корзина.png"))
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setFixedSize(1800, 750)

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgba(230, 230, 250, 1)')

        layoutV = QVBoxLayout(self)

        layoutV.addWidget(self.scroll)

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setStyleSheet('background-color: #c5d0e6')

        

        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

        self.gbox1 = QGridLayout(self.widget)


        """
        button_delete = QPushButton(self)
        button_delete.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet_1)
        button_delete.setText('Delete')
        button_delete.setGeometry(1675, 685, 60, 60)


        def Buy(self):
            buy = LoginForm()
            buy.exec_()
        
        button_buy = QPushButton(self)
        button_buy.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet_1)
        button_buy.setText('Купить')
        button_buy.setGeometry(1740, 685, 60, 60)
        button_buy.clicked.connect(Buy)
        """
   



        
        



       
        

    
        


StyleSheet_1 = '''
/* настройка кнопки при статике */
QPushButton {
    background-color: #c5d0e6;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
    
    
}

/* настройка кнопки при наведении */
QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: #c5d0e6;
} 

/* настройка кнопки при активе */
QPushButton:pressed { 
    background-color: #c5d0e6; 
}
'''



if __name__ == '__main__':      
    aplicacion = QApplication(sys.argv)
    aplicacion.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 10))
    Window = Korzina()
    Window.show()
    sys.exit(aplicacion.exec_())
```

This widget I'm trying to add to the window
[image]

The window where the widget should be added:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create config.py and create the vars to be shared:

config.py:

```
X = 0
Y = "empty"
```

You can share a global Variable Across Python Modules using "config" import.
For example, we have to files FileA and FileB and we want to share var X and Y from FileA to FileB:

FileA:

```
import config
config.X = 10
config.Y = "hello"
```

FileB:

```
import config
import update

print(config.X)
print(config.Y)
```

Output:

```
10
hello
```

Comment: The console shows: AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'widget1'

Comment: what code did you write?

Comment: I wrote in another file witch named is config: **x = QGridLayout()** , and i used this varible in following  classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a combobox(after create, you need to do combobox.hide()) and when you want them to show up you can do combobox.show() . But using stacked widget is way more easy and useful. By doing so, you can switch between the widgets rather than show and hide them.